# Isometries with $f(p) = g(p)$ and $df_p=dg_p$ implies $f = g$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

I am facing the following problem of one of the first chapters of a course about Differential Geometry. We have this definition of isometry:

A function $f:S_1 \longrightarrow S_2 $ with $S_1$ and $S_2$ regular surfaces is an isometry if $f$ is a diffeomorphism and $<df_p(v),df_p(w)>=<v,w>$ $\forall p \in S_1, v, \ w \in T_pS_1$.

The problem is: Let $S$ be a connected surface and $f,g:S \longrightarrow S'$ two isometries. Prove that if there is a point $p \in S$ such that $f(p)=g(p)$, $df_p=dg_p$ then $f=g$.

I have tried this but got stuck. Let $q$ be a point of $S$ and let $\alpha$ a regular curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha(1)=q$. Then $f(\alpha(0))=g(\alpha(0))$ and $df_p(\alpha'(0)) = dg_p(\alpha'(0))$ so that the regular curves $f \circ \alpha$ and $g \circ \alpha$ and its derivatives are equal at $t=0$. I could not prove that $f \circ \alpha = g\circ \alpha$ so that $f(q)=g(q)$.

Comment: Have you learned about geodesics yet?

Comment: Usually, a very useful technique to prove that the set where something happens is an entire connected manifold, is to prove that such set is both an open and a closed subset of the manifold. It works here, although I don't know how familiar are you with geodesics and the exponential map. Anyway, it is proved in Proposition 5.6.2 of Petersen's Riemannian Geometry, 3rd edition. You may have to read a lot first to understand the proof. I don't know any easier proof.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161551/572257, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2660176/572257 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604860/show-that-two-isometries-induce-the-same-linear-mapping